# 'std::out_of_range' en virtual function

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con una *virtual function* en una clase. Estoy tratando de acceder a los elementos de una *virtual function* que se declara en la Clase 1 y luego se define en la Clase 2. Entiendo que el error `std :: out_of_range` es un problema de acceso a la memoria, pero no entiendo el problema en el código `main ()` para acceder a los valores. Al llamar a la función **`m-> función (t, j)`** No puedo acceder a los elementos de *`parmem`*, pero si llamo directamente a la salida de la función funciona: **`parmem.at (1). gamma`**. Aquí está el código:

Class 1:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

class Class1
{
public:
    mat Y;        

    struct Par
    {
            mat gamma;
    } par;
    std::vector<Par> parmem ;  
    virtual double function( const int t, const int j ) = 0;  
};
```

Class2:

```
class Class2 : public Class1
{
public:

        virtual double function( const int t, const int j );   
};


double Class2::function( const int t, const int j )
{
        cout << parmem.at(t).gamma << endl;
        return j+t;
}
```

main():

```
int main()
{
        mat Y=randu<mat>(3,3);

        int t=1;
        int j=1; 

        Class2 *m = new Class2;

        std::vector<Class1::Par> parmem {
                {Y},
                {2*Y}
        };

        cout << parmem.at(1).gamma << endl; //funciona
        cout << m->function(t,j) << endl;  //no funciona
        return 0; 
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si consultamos la función [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), podemos ver que lanza la excepción [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).

Ese error sucede cuando pides un elemento más allá de los contenidos en el `std::vector`, que es exáctamente lo que ha pasado:

1. `Class1` contiene un `std::vector`, que se construye por defecto con **cero** elementos.
2. `Class2` hereda de `Class1` y en consecuencia contiene también `Class1::parmem`.
3. Creas una instancia de `Class2`:

   ```
   Class2 *m = new Class2;
   ```

   Dicha instancia contiene un vector con **cero** elementos, pues no se le ha asignado ninguno.
4. Accedes a una función de `Class2` que pide el segundo elemento del vector interno de `Class1`, que al estar vacío: lanza la excepción.

Comment: Pero al definir  std::vector<Class1::Par> parmem {{Y}, {2*Y}}; le estaría diciendo que parmem del Class1 tiene dos elementos? Porque al correr parmem.at(1).gamma si me entrega el output, pero si lo hago desde la function(t,j) muestra el error.

Comment: El vector `parmem` declarado en `main` no tiene relación alguna con el vector `parmem` declarado en `Class1`; se llaman igual pero son vectores completamente distintos e independientes.